# Replacing a certain value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe by reading in two different datasets as csv files.

At the minute, the data frame prints out something like this:

```
     Name     Value 1     Value 2     Value 3    Value 4    Value 5
0     A          1          3           4           5          2
1     B          4          5           6           6          7
2     C          7          1           3           8          0
3     D          2          3           6           9          8
4     E          5          10          11          4          6
5     F          7          1           0           7          8
```

Although the actual dataframe has over 200 rows.
Is there a way, for example, for the letter B, to change the value in the column named Value 3 from 6 to 8?

Comment: Yes since  you are able to read in the csv files, you would now what to use a for loop to indent through the values until it reach a certain column then replace that value with the value you want. Once it is done your will write it out in a new csv files or you can append it.

Comment: you don't need to do all that, are you looking to change all of the '6's' in Value 3 or just a single one?

Comment: @d_kennetz Hi, yes im just looking to change that single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + Boolean indexing

You can use `loc` with Boolean indexing:-

```
df.loc[df['Value 3'].eq(6) & df['Name'].eq('B'), 'Value 3'] = 8
```

If equality to 6 is not a requirement, you can simply omit the first Boolean condition.

#### [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

If your `Name` series is unique and you want to update a value, irrespective of its *current* value, recommended practice is to make `Name` your index, then use `at` for scalar setting:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
df.at['B', 'Value 3'] = 8
```